# Why can't I use a call function on a function result?

Tags: javascript

I want to call `each()` on the resulting array of another function that I call.

Why can't I do:

```
callMethodThatReturnsAnArray().each(function () {
    ...
});
```

I get a `callMethodThatReturnsAnArray(...).each is not a function` error.

Comment: Please, show the implementation of `callMethodThatReturnsAnArray()`.

Comment: Because if it is an array of js elements, the method is `forEach`

Comment: He may be using jQuery, which I believe does have a `.each()` method.

Comment: yes but the jquery each method is called in this way: `$.each(array, fn());`

Comment: that is correct, but you should use that like this : `$.each(callMethodThatReturnsAnArray(), function( ...`

Comment: @MatthewBrown: Yes, but not on arrays.

Comment: Your syntax is fine, it's just that JavaScript arrays don't have an `each` method. You probably meant [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). More details in the linked question's answers.

Comment: if you *did* want to use this syntax per se, you could just add it to the Array prototype : `Array.prototype.each = function(lambda)
    {
       for(var i =0; i < this.length; i++)
       {
          lambda(this[i]);
       }
    }` should work in your case

Comment: @TimothyGroote: It's extremely poor practice to add enumerable properties to `Array.prototype`. If you're going to suggest something like this, I strongly recommend showing how to do it without creating an enumerable property (e.g., via `Object.defineProperty` or similar).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder guess i should have elaborated a little more, but yeah, agreed ; this is indeed *bad* practice. i was halfway through making an answer post when the question got closed, so i kinda though scr-- it.

Answer (score 4):

`each()` is jQuery for DOM elements - what are you doing exactly? For plain Javascript, you'll want to use `forEach()` or `map()`

Comment: Not just for dom elements per se ;)

Comment: Indeed, jQuery objects *can*, rarely, hold other things. And jQuery has no monopoly on `each`. Still, going with the odds...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder since jQuery arrays are little more than glorified arrays, most of the guts of jQuery counts on selector results behaving exactly like an array. vice versa, many jQuery functions can be used to work with plain arrays of just about anything

Comment: @TimothyGroote: jQuery *objects* are indeed very array-like. Re holding non-DOM elements: That's what I said. For instance, you often end up with a jQuery object (not array) as the result from [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) (and then you use `get` to get the actual array -- or rather, you did a few years back, nowadays jQuery's `map` is rarely useful).

Answer (score 0):

Array has forEach method not each. Use

```
callMethodThatReturnsAnArray().forEach(function(entry) {
// ...do whatever you want to do
```

});

If you want to use each, Jquery has method

```
jQuery.each(array, callback )
```

So you can write code something like.

```
$.each(callMethodThatReturnsAnArray(), function(index, value){// do whatever you want to do.});
```